# cordova: how to call method after all modules are loaded

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, cordova-3

I am using Cordova and I'm using some plugins too. So now I want to do the task after all of the plugins/modules are loaded. How to achieve this in Cordova? Does Cordova provide any `callback` after the plugins are loaded?

I have used onload but now i want some alternate to it. Is there some callback provided by Cordova to be called after all modules are loaded.

Comment: I am not getting exactly your scenarios.But if you loaded any plugin.
Check for its output, from it you will get triggering point.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `deviceready`. Check out the example ....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Device Ready Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    function onLoad() {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    }

    function onDeviceReady() {
        // Now safe to use device APIs
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="onLoad()">
  </body>
</html>
```

... from [the documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_events_events.md.html).

Comment: this i don't want to use, I mean onload i don't want to use. Is cordova is giving some callbacks to be called after all modules are loaded.

Comment: I'm not aware of any other way. Question for me is _why_ don't you want to use `onLoad()`?